# Intellij parsing java code

Tags: java, parsing, math, intellij-idea

I want to use a math-expression parser of java code. In particular I would like to convert a math-expression given as String to an abstract syntax tree consisted of separate nodes.

Is there anyone to recommend me a relevant open source tool?

If no, how do you reckon the possibility to exploit Intellij source code to do this work? 
Which classes are responsible for code parsing and analysis?

Are they included in idea.jar? How can I easily infiltrate their functionality (methods etc)?

I am speaking exclusively for Intellij.

Comment: I would download the open source copy. Its a massive code base and I wouldn't know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/Basic+Syntax) library.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the results of the math-expression you should revise the question and the answer i selected months ago:

[Java 1.5: mathematical formula parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031824/java-1-5-mathematical-formula-parser)

Brieff description: use the java integration with dinamyc languajes like javascript to let them do the work for you

Answer (score 1):

I would not use IntelliJ, as much as I love it.

If you need an AST, look no further than ANTLR.  If you can write a grammar for your equations, ANTLR can generate a lexer/parser to create it for you.